# Encoding series of bitmap images into HD video using c++ and Visual Studio

Tags: image, video, h.264

I am looking for an way to get images in stack and encode it into H264 or any other HD Video format. I am working with Visual Studio, and in search of some tutorial with c++ implementation. It would be great to have your feedbacks and suggestions

Regards,
Venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

Try FFmpeg... it's easy to learn. Download the precompiled version (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Compile FFmpeg for Windows is not that easy.

Start from [docs/demuxing_decoding](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/demuxing_decoding_8c-example.html) and [docs/decoding_encoding.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/doc_2examples_2decoding_encoding_8c-example.html). These samples are very straightforward for beginners with video. Then you will be able to understand the basics of muxing/demuxing, encoding/decoding.

Comment: Hi Wagner Thanks for your response, I have already downloaded it and added the headers of it in Visual Studio. But i am searching some tutorial for converting series of bit map images into videos. I couldnt clearly find one helping me in this regard...

Comment: this is one of the easiest ways... based on it, you can convert series of bitmaps... in fact, these samples almost do it. you better understand them.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response again. I am checking it. I am too seeing the Windows Media Foundation they have pretty cool H264Encoder and Decoders. But I am not really sure whether i can use stack of images as Input. I couldnt find any tutorial regarding this too... Do you have any idea regarding this..?

Comment: you must understand C/C++ in order to do that. again, if you understand the samples, you can do it. if you don't understand it, you don't know C/C++ and won't be able to do it any other way... those samples are very straightforward. It's ready for you. You must code the opening of bitmaps by yourself instead of create dynamically as in the sample. If you don't know how to do that, I can't help you... I must assume you know a little bit of programming, C/C++ and what a bitmap is. If you don't know, please study how a bitmap works. ;-)